# Ist it possible to check the peer address before accepting a TCP connection?

Tags: perl, tcp, socket

I wrote a simple Perl server that listens on a TCP port/socket, accepting connections.
Now I wonder:

When wanting to implement address-based access control, is it possible to check the address of the peer requesting a connection before accepting it?

If possible I could reject the connection request (I hope) instead of accepting the connection and the immediately closing it again.

Comment: Even if you can get the address, there seems to be no portable way to `reject()` the connection. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590847/how-can-i-refuse-a-socket-connection-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TCP/IP connection is established by the kernel and then your application gets to work with the connection.

The only way to filter/prevent unneeded connections is by using a kernel firewall. You've not specified your OS, but in Linux that'll be iptables/nftables.

Comment: My idea was: You `listen` to a socket, and the socket signals that there is a connection request, basically un-blocking `accept`. So my idea was whether I could query the pending connection requests and somehow deny the request. However, as it seems, it's not possible under application control, but only from the kernel firewall (netfolter).

Comment: I deliberately did not specify the variant of UNIX, because I would have preferred a solution that works on "any UNIX" (even though I'm using Linux)).

Comment: @U.Windl I haven't yet tried it myself, but by a combination of using Wireshark to monitor a connection while stepping a client and server program, so can pause execution between ``listen`` and ``accept`` calls, you could see at which point the network stack in the Kernel has completed the _TCP 3-Way Handshake Process_.

Answer (score 5):

Not really an answer, but a few pointers too long for comments:

On MacOS X `man accept` says:

> **One can obtain user connection request data without confirming the connection by issuing a recvmsg(2) call with an msg_iovlen of 0 and a non-zero msg_controllen**, or by issuing a getsockopt(2) request.  Similarly, one can provide user connection rejection information by issuing a
> sendmsg(2) call with providing only the control information, or by calling setsockopt(2).

(emphasis mine)

Can't find any more details in `man recvmsg`, `man getsockopt` or `man tcp` on that topic though.

On Debian, `man accept` says:

> In order to be notified of incoming connections on a socket, you can use select(2), poll(2), or epoll(7).  A readable event will be delivered when a new connection is attempted and you may then call accept() to get a socket for that connection.   Alternatively,  you  can
> set the socket to deliver SIGIO when activity occurs on a socket; see socket(7) for details.

IMHO the only one in there which **may** be able to deliver more info would be `epoll`.

But even if you can get actually the info, I'm not quite sure how you would reject the connection if you don't like it.

You're probably better off doing the filtering at the network stack/firewall level (iptables and friends).

Comment: The `getsockopt` is an interesting idea: I found `IP_MSFILTER` (since Linux 2.4.22 / 2.5.68) that is intended for multicast filtering (RFC 3376: "*Version 3 of IGMP adds support for "source filtering", that is, the ability for a system to report interest in receiving packets* ***only*** *from specific source addresses, or from* ***all but*** *specific source addresses, sent to a particular multicast address.*"). Would be interesting trying to mis-use that for non-multicast.

Comment: Also interesting could be ` IP_PKTINFO` (since Linux 2.2) "*that supplies some information about the incoming packet.*".

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim any expertise in Perl - but I suspect it is not possible. For controlling access to a server I would restrict (in order of preference):

1. By interface / bind address
2. By kernel firewall (iptables, nftables, eBPF)
3. By TCP wrappers or host config

Given that the facility to restrict by host config does not currently exist, apparently choosing this as the starting point seems unusual.

Assuming that 1 and 2 above are *not* an option, then I would suggest using TCP wrappers from your Perl code. This should get you up and running with minimal code changes while leveraging a flexible, standard and robust mechanism for network access control. See also https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::TCPwrappers

I believe its also possible to apply tcp-wrappers by tweaking the LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime (i.e. without any code changes) but couldn't find reference to this in a quick Google search.

Comment: As I understand it, `libwrap` also accepts the connections first, just to close them immediately if access is denied. So probably the only way (except from dealing with Linux raw sockets) is to use the kernel firewall to block access before accepting the connections.

Answer (score -1):

Transmission control protocol is not used for Access control.

I advise you to check TLS https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Besides, have a look to netfilter firewall input hooks. You can drop and reject unwanted peers.